# How to find parent_message_id of reply message in graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I mean that Incoming reply mail is which mail reply,
To find this I want parent_message_id by using this I'm easily find parent_mail.

below code is respone of reply mail.
I want to find It's parent mail means below mail is which mail reply
To find parent mail I want parent_mail_id How can I find this ?

```
{
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAABexZ50mSS0TKajvW/Uc3jZAAAhk64J\"",
        "id": "AQMkADAwATM3ZmYAZS01OWRhLTM5MjgtMDACLTAw....",
        "createdDateTime": "2023-02-02T08:39:59Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-02-02T08:40:01Z",
        "changeKey": "CQAAABYAAABexZ50mSS0TKajvW/Uc3jZAAAhk64J",
        "categories": [],
        "receivedDateTime": "2023-02-02T08:40:00Z",
        "sentDateTime": "2023-02-02T08:39:46Z",
        "hasAttachments": false,
        "internetMessageId": "<CAJjLavQHv0SDMHxiKpRUCE=NU9X4AnL2QfPKjLJMbPeudvNP-A@mail.gmail.com>",
        "subject": "Re: Meet for lunch 12:40?",
        "bodyPreview": "12:40 reply mail\r\n\r\nOn Thu, 2 Feb 2023 at 13:06, ** <****@outlook.com> wrote:\r\nThe new cafeteria is open.",
        "importance": "normal",
        "parentFolderId": "AQMkADAwATM3ZmYAZS01OWRhLTM5MjgtMDACLTAwCgAuAAADNqdil3J7jU_HbfQfdBJYbQEAXsWedJkktEymo71v1HN42QAAAgEMAAAA",
        "conversationId": "AQQkADAwATM3ZmYAZS01OWRhLTM5MjgtMDACLTAwCgAQAAo6snnrhhJOv0qLJ4Io1Fo=",
        "conversationIndex": "AQHZNtkeCjqyeeuGEk6/SosngijUWq67VhwA",
        "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": null,
        "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
        "isRead": false,
        "isDraft": false,
        "webLink": "https://outlook.live.com/owa/?ItemID=AQMkADAwATM3ZmYAZS01OWRhLTM5MjgtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADNqdil3J7jU%2BHbfQfdBJYbQcAXsWedJkktEymo71v1HN42QAAAgEMAAAAXsWedJkktEymo71v1HN42QAAACGV0fkAAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
        "inferenceClassification": "focused",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "html",
            "content": "<html><head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"></head><body><div dir=\"ltr\">12:40 reply mail&nbsp;</div><br><div class=\"gmail_quote\"><div dir=\"ltr\" class=\"gmail_attr\">On Thu, 2 Feb 2023 at 13:06, ** &lt;<a href=\"mailto:***@outlook.com\">***@outlook.com</a>&gt; wrote:<br></div><blockquote class=\"gmail_quote\" style=\"margin:0px 0px 0px 0.8ex; border-left:1px solid rgb(204,204,204); padding-left:1ex\">The new cafeteria is open.</blockquote></div></body></html>"
        },
        "sender": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "****",
                "address": "***@gmail.com"
            }
        },
        "from": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "****",
                "address": "****"
            }
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "***",
                    "address": "****@outlook.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "ccRecipients": [],
        "bccRecipients": [],
        "replyTo": [],
        "flag": {
            "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
        }
    },
```

I've send mail by using `/sendMail` graph api and for this sent mail I've reply mail by using other platform(ex:gmail) ,So how can I know incoming message parent message I mean which message reply is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There Isn't Any way to find parent_id by using reply mail response , In response provide parent_folderId but It Isn't useful to find parent_id

There Is one way to find parent_id If parent and reply messages have same conversation-id but Isn't then It cannot be possible to find the correct parent message

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the `conversationId` from your message and filter messages by `conversationId`

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=conversationId eq '{conversation_id}'
```

Then order the messages by conversation index. The property `conversationIndex` does not support filtering on the server, so you need to order messages on the client as a string.

From ordered messages you are able to get the parent message.

Comment: Don't understand clearly Can you please explain in brief

Comment: Parent and reply both message conversationId and conversationIndex is different

Comment: @BhavyaArdeshana Could you update the question and share details about parent and reply message? But if parent and reply messages have different conversationId it cannot be possible to find the correct parent message

Comment: Yes I've send mail by using /sendMail graph api and for this sent mail I've reply mail by using other platform(ex:gmail) ,So how can I know incoming message parent message I mean which message reply is it ?